# How to put texture in .obj file while using libgdx libs for android?

Tags: android, libgdx

How to add texture in .obj file from .mtl file because libgdx can't render .mtl file.

Comment: I would also like to to know this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems there :

- You cannot exploit `.mtl` yet (june 2012) in libgdx.
- `.obj` format does not include textures (textures are described in the `.mtl` file).

But the solution is to ignore completely the MTL file and manually add your texture when you load your model.

sample code :

```
public load3dModel( String objfile, String texfile )
{
   ModelLoaderHints hint = new ModelLoaderHints(false);             
   m_mesh = ModelLoaderRegistry.loadStillModel(Gdx.files.internal(objfile), hint);
   Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(texfile), Format.RGBA4444, false);
   Material mat = new Material("mat",
                               new TextureAttribute(texture, 0, "u_Texture"));
   m_mesh.setMaterial(mat);
   ...
```

Comment: I have no such classes like `ModelLoaderHints`, `ModelLoaderRegistry` and `TextureAttribute` in my version of libgdx-0.9.7

Comment: You have them in the "extension/model-loaders" part of libgdx (as a side effect these files are not packaged in the core libgdx library and must me compiled by yourself)

Comment: As you said: `You cannot exploit .mtl yet (june 2012) in libgdx`. Does it work now? If you have any example how to add texture using .mtl file, please share it